# Gerar um gráfico do Google Charts com registros do banco Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Olá amigos programadores estou precisando de uma ajuda.

Estou tentando gerar um gráfico com o Google Chats de agendamentos por mês, porém no banco de dados as datas salvas são no formato xx/xx/xxxx.
Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar de maneira que eu consiga colocar os meses estaticamente ou dinamicamente se converter todas as datas em meses por extenso e a quantidade no gráfico.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Meses', 'Agendamentos'],

    <?php
    include('connection.php');

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(agend_id) AS qtd FROM agendamento GROUP BY MONTH(agend_data)");

    $meses = [];
    while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $mes = array_push($meses, "Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril");
        $qtd = $dados['qtd'];
    ?>

      ['<?php print_r($mes); ?>', <?php echo $qtd; ?>],

    <?php } ?>
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}


 </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Estrutura do banco]

[image: Gráfico gerado]

O gráfico acima é que conseguir gerar mas está faltando apenas os meses no X do gráfico.

Agradeço desde já qualquer tipo de ajuda.

Comment: você pode formar a data que para o formato que quiser usando as funções do `mysql`, [dê uma olhada na documentação do `DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Ricardo teria como mostrar como ficaria neste contexto de query?